# How do you pass a SAS dataset as a paramteter in a macro?

Tags: sas, include, sas-macro

I have a program "P" saved outside my project that I can call within any project use with an %include statement; it outputs a table called P_OUTPUT. I want to be able to pass a data table D that I've created within my project to "P" and have "P" use the information in the DataTable in an SQL statement in "P".

I'm not sure how to pass a data table as a parameter in SAS. I've created the table in WORK called WORK.D

```
%macro 
%let A = %sysfunc(open(work.D));
%include 'X:\P.sas';
%mend
```

in "P"

```
Proc SQL;
Create table P_OUTPUT AS 
SELECT …
WHERE Column IN (SELECT * FROM &D.)
;
Quit;
```

I get the error:
ERROR: You cannot open WORK.D.DATA for output access with member-level control because WORK.D.DATA is in use by you in resource environment IOM ROOT COMP ENV.

How do I solution this?

Comment: I don't understand. To pass a dataset to a macro you pass the NAME of the dataset as the value of a parameter. Then expand the parameter (local macro variable) to use the NAME in the SAS code that you want the macro to generate.  What SAS code is your macro trying to generate?  Where does the name of the dataset need to appear in that code?

Comment: I've edited the code, made a mistake mixing up names of the table

Comment: Why are you calling the OPEN() function?  Just use `%let D=work.D;` to get the name of the dataset into the macro variable you are using to contain the name of the dataset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To pass a dataset to a macro you can pass the NAME of the dataset. Example:

```
%macro mymacro(indsname);
  proc print data=&indsname;
  run;
%mend mymacro;
%mymacro(indsname=sashelp.class);
```

Your error message just means you already have that dataset open somewhere so SAS cannot open it again.

Why do you have the call to the OPEN() function?  That is not doing anything useful and might even be why you cannot create the dataset.  If want WORK.D as the value of the macro variable D then just do that.

```
%let D=work.D;
```

Then when you expand D in your later code it generates valid SAS syntax.

Comment: So, what't you're saying is just assign it to D with %let before my %include statement? Then when "P" runs which references "&D.", it should be good? What is the syntax within P to say do Proc SQL; Create table WORK.TEST AS Select * from "&D."; Quit; ???

Comment: Why would you put quotes around a dataset name?  In SAS code you use quotes around string literals.